# Laravel 5 many to many attach two columns not working

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

in my Laravel 5 application i have many to many relationship between two models.I'm using a pivot table to keep track of them. In my both models i have defined belongsToMany method with relevant pivot table name as parameter.Then i'm going to add values to the pivot table in controller. It works fine for only one column. For the other one it's not inserting any values. In the Controller i'm calling like this,

```
$this->mymodel->addToPivotTable($values);
```

Should i pass two parameters there?

Answer (score 0):

I could able to solve this. I needed to call the method after saving my data set to the table.It's like this,

```
public function add(Request $request){
        $post = $request->all();

        $arr = array(1,4,5);

        $result = $this->mymodel->create($post);

        $result->classifications()->attach($arr);

}
```